# Why SQL allowed subqueries without FROM clause?

Tags: sql

Why SQL allowed subqueries without FROM clause? I cannot find an example in which it is necessary.
For example:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT count(a)) FROM t;
-- equivalent to
SELECT count(a) FROM t;

SELECT (SELECT count(*)) FROM t;
-- equivalent to
SELECT 1 FROM t;

SELECT a, sum(b) FROM t GROUP BY a ORDER BY (SELECT sum(b));
-- equivalent to
SELECT a, sum(b) sum_b FROM t GROUP BY a ORDER BY sum_b;
```

Most subqueries are with FROM clause, which is intuitive.

Subqueries without FROM clause seem unnecessary.

Please somebody help me, thanks!!!

Comment: Think of `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. Without the PostgreSQL extensions `UPDATE .... FROM` and `DELETE ... USING`, how would you want to refer to another table? But the real answer is a counter-question: why shouldn't SQL allow subqueries?

Comment: These RDBMS allow queries without a FROM clause so why should subqueries be restricted in a way queries aren't? It can be useful sometimes to do things like `WHERE EXISTS(SELECT col1 INTERSECT SELECT col2)` in RDBMS that don't support IS DISTINCT FROM to give an example where this is useful

Comment: i would read `(SELECT count(*)) ` as `(SELECT count(*) FROM dual) ` , where the table object dual was reduced, as unnecessary

Comment: A subquery is allowed to reference columns from outer table, it is standard behavior. E.g. you can do `select (select bar from t2 where t2.id = t1.id) from t1`

Answer (score -1):

An RDBMS, that is, a Relational DataBase Management System works with relations via relational algebra.

A relation or a table (the two terms are synonyms) is a set of records. Your `FROM` clause specifies that records are to be taken from a specific table (or some joined relation if there are joins as well after the from), which specifies the source of your records.

Yet, you are perfectly able to run

```
SELECT 'ABC';
```

without putting this into a sub-query, because as an alternative to `FROM`, you are allowed to define your relations. In your

```
SELECT (SELECT count(a)) FROM t;
```

Query, you specify your own relation in the sub-query, using the `a` field's `count` that's available there. It looks unintuitive indeed, but an RDBMS will not protect you from writing unintuitive code, rather it will allow you to specify your own relations if you so please and trusts you that you know what you are doing.

Since

1. You are allowed to specify your own relation even outside of any sub-queries
2. You are allowed to write sub-queries

it follows that you are allowed to combine the two, that is, specify your own relation inside of such sub-queries.